# Algorithm for calculating number of ways to put a line of balls in boxes

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm thinking of an algorithm for calculating the number of ways to partition balls, here is the setup of the problem:

1. The balls are in a line with numbers, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...N, we cannot change the order of the balls.
2. We want to group the balls into boxes, and we can use any number of boxes but no box can be empty.
3. Two groups are considered the same only if they are identical in number of boxes and the balls for corresponding boxes.

One example of grouping the balls is `|1, 2|3, 4, 5|6|` and it is (obviously) different from `|1, 2, 3|4, 5|6|`

I would like to calculate the number of ways of grouping the balls. Normally I would try a brutal force search but I don't even know where to start.

And here is some interesting extensions of the problem:

1. What is we have the requirement that the number of balls in a latter box needs to be equal to or larger than the previous box? For example, we can do `|1|2, 3|4, 5|6, 7, 8|` but we cannot do `|1, 2, 3|4, 5|6, 7, 8|`
2. What if the number of balls in a latter box needs to be at least k times of its previous box, where k is a given value and is at least 1?

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem of [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).
Formula is rather simple - there is `2^(n-1)` compositions.

The first extension is the problem of [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).
There is no closed-formula known.
[Example of implementation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675382/calculating-integer-partitions) of Euler's pentagonal number theorem

For the second extension it is possible to make recursive function like this (not checked, just idea)

```
def partsktimes(x, current, k)
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    result = 0
    for i in range(current*k, x+1):
        result += partsktimes(x - i, i, k)
```